# How can I base a KQL query off a csv file of email addresses?

Tags: azure-active-directory, kql, azure-log-analytics

I have a csv file with 50,000 user principal names (UPNs) for which I have to pull sign-in logs that show at least one successful sign-in via a Conditional Access Policy for Multi-factor Authentication (MFA).

I think I have the beginnings of a query that finds the information, but I don't know how to have it search specifically against my list of UPNs.

This is what I've tried so far:

It would nice if I could show the columns I listed in the "project" operator, but that doesn't seem to be working the way I planned either. The most important thing though, is querying by the UPNs in my csv file. I know the Azure Log Analytics has a ceiling of 30K records, but I'm planning to divide my csv file into smaller batches.

Warning: KQL Newbie -- Only a few days so far of swim/sink learning for my job.

```
SigninLogs
| mvexpand ConditionalAccessPolicies
| where TimeGenerated <= ago(13d)
| where ConditionalAccessPolicies.id == "4603056e-3712-4d0f-8d51-59ec0bd66261"
| where ConditionalAccessStatus == "success"
| where UserPrincipalName  contains "@my.tccd.edu"
| project TimeGenerated, UserPrincipalName, AppDisplayName, ConditionalAccessPolicies.displayName
| summarize count=count() by UserPrincipalName
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the awesome world of KQL, you'll love it here :)

Unfortunately I don't have access to a dataset like yours to give you actual code that I know will work, but based on a couple of things I've put together some pointers for you.

Having a query off of 50,000 UPNs points in the direction of having that CSV hosted somewhere on the internet that you can grab within Log Analytics.  As you said you will be better splitting this CSV up into smaller chunks.  You can zip this CSV up to help make things a little faster.  Do this with `externaldata` operator.

If you have 50,000 UPNs my assumption is you will have many more logon events than users.  Therefore keeping the smaller table (UPNs) on the left hand side of a `join` will be more performant.

```
let EmailAddresses = (externaldata (UserPrincipalName:string) [h@'https://www.notawebsite.com/sometotallyrandomdirectorytohelpwithhidingit/EmailAddresses-part1.csv.zip']; //CSV here in a zip file with an appropiate name
EmailAddresses
| join kind=leftouter (
SigninLogs
| where TimeGenerated <= ago(13d) //You should have time based queries at the top of your query
| where ConditionalAccessStatus == "success"
| where UserPrincipalName has "@my.tccd.edu" //"has" is better in this case and it could make things quicker
| summarize LogonEvents = count() by UserPrincipalName, ConiditionalAccessPolicies
) on UserPrincipalName
| mvexpand ConditionalAccessPolicies //"mvexpand" is relatively computationally expensive, I like to keep it right at the end
```

Comment: Hi "Gyp the Cat":

Thank you for replying. Could you clarify something for me, please?

Would an Azure Storage Account be a suitable place to hose my csv file? If not, what would you recommend?

And what's the best way to convert a csv file into a table that Log Analytics can join with the SignIn-Logs table that's in my Azure workspace?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi David, an Azure SA would absolutely be suitable.  Use the web share functionality to host your CSV.  As for the "convert a csv file into a table" that's the bit in the code above which starts "let EmailAddresses = (externaldate (...", that is the schema and location for the CSV.

Comment: Hi "Gyp the Cat": -- You've gotten me close. The only problem is I'm getting a message saying that an access denied error prevented the system from accessing the storage account.  -- The query wants to reach out to the file share, but it's getting blocked.  -- I made sure my account has contributor roles for log analysis and smb file share -- and the url is copied directoy from the csv file properties.  -- Any last minute tips I can explore?

Comment: Trying going for publicly accessible for testing purposes, this guide seems to be the most prescriptive for this specific task:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/microsoft-azure-hosting-a-static-website-with-azure-storage/

Shameless (but very relevant) self publicity I host some CSVs to the public for KQL on a storage account, for example:

externaldata (CIDR:string, CIDRASN:int, CIDRASNName:string, CIDRSource:string) ['https://firewalliplists.gypthecat.com/lists/kusto/kusto-cidr-asn.csv.zip'] with (ignoreFirstRecord=true)